# How to convert a pytorch tensor into a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

How do I convert a torch tensor to numpy?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

copied from [pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/tensor_tutorial.html):

```
a = torch.ones(5)
print(a)
```

> tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])

```
b = a.numpy()
print(b)
```

> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

---

Following from the below discussion with @John:

In case the tensor is (or can be) on GPU, or in case it (or it can) require grad, one can use

```
t.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

I recommend to uglify your code only as much as required.

Comment: In my copy of torch better make that a.detach().cpu().numpy()

Comment: @LarsEricson why?

Comment: what would the complexity be to convert tensor to NumPy like this?

Comment: @Sid I believe `o(1)` in most cases, but not always. See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/utils/tensor_numpy.cpp and https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/c-api/array.html#c.PyArray_SetBaseObject

Comment: @Gulzar the detach() is necessary to avoid computing gradients and the cpu() is necessary if the Tensor is in gpu memory

Comment: @John this is not necessary in the general case.

Comment: @Gulzar can you be more specific?  What isn't necessary (there were 2 functions listed) and what do you mean by "in the general case?"

consider this question/answer for more detail:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582590/why-do-we-call-detach-before-calling-numpy-on-a-pytorch-tensor

Comment: @John The usage of `detach` and `cpu` is understood. The question here was about converting a torch tensor to a numpy array. numpy arrays are always on cpu, and always don't have gradient calculation involved with them. If the torch tensor is on gpu or needs to be detached, that is beside the point of this question. So, *always* doing `.detach().cpu()` is overkill. Doing it when necessary is good, but this isn't the general case.

Comment: This is true, although I believe both are noops if unnecessary so the overkill is only in the typing and there's some value if writing a function that accepts a Tensor of unknown provenance.  I apologize for misunderstanding your original question to Lars.  To summarize, `detach` and `cpu` are not necessary in every case, but are necessary in perhaps the most common case (so there's value in mentioning them).  `numpy` is necessary in every case but is often insufficient on its own.  Any future persons should reference the question linked above or the pytorch documentation for more information.

Answer (score 12):

You can try following ways

```
1. torch.Tensor().numpy()
2. torch.Tensor().cpu().data.numpy()
3. torch.Tensor().cpu().detach().numpy()
```

Answer (score 5):

Another useful way :

```
a = torch(0.1, device='cuda')

a.cpu().data.numpy()
```

Answer

> array(0.1, dtype=float32)

Comment: What is the benefit of including `.data.` ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a function from [fastai core](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/384fe1f7bb53fad844a2dd918e71bec61ae66df4/fastai/torch_core.py#L225):

```py
def to_np(x):
    "Convert a tensor to a numpy array."
    return apply(lambda o: o.data.cpu().numpy(), x)
```

Possible using a function from prospective PyTorch library is a nice choice.

If you look inside [PyTorch Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/) you will find this [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/a75c64d80c76c3dc71f735d9197a4a601847e0cd/examples/bertology/run_bertology.py#L113):

```py
preds = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

So you may ask why the `detach()` method is needed? It is needed when we would like to detach the tensor from AD computational graph.

Still note that the CPU tensor and numpy array **are connected**. They share the same storage:

```
import torch
tensor = torch.zeros(2)
numpy_array = tensor.numpy()
print('Before edit:')
print(tensor)
print(numpy_array)

tensor[0] = 10

print()
print('After edit:')
print('Tensor:', tensor)
print('Numpy array:', numpy_array)
```

Output:

```
Before edit:
tensor([0., 0.])
[0. 0.]

After edit:
Tensor: tensor([10.,  0.])
Numpy array: [10.  0.]
```

The value of the first element is shared by the tensor and the numpy array. Changing it to 10 in the tensor changed it in the numpy array as well.

This is why we need to be careful, since altering the numpy array my alter the CPU tensor as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following two functions useful.

1. [torch.Tensor.numpy()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.numpy)
2. [torch.from_numpy()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=numpy#torch.from_numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if there's "applied" gradient, you'll first have to put `.detach()` function before the `.numpy()` function.

```
loss = loss_fn(preds, labels)
print(loss.detach().numpy())
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = torch.tensor([0.1,0.32], device='cuda:0')

x.detach().cpu().data.numpy()
```

Comment: Code only answer are not great. Please explain why you consider this code to answer the question.