# Why is looping through pytorch tensors so slow (compared to Numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I've been working with image transformations recently and came to a situation where I have a large array (shape of 100,000 x 3) where each row represents a point in 3D space like:

```py
pnt = [x y z]
```

All I'm trying to do is iterating through each point and matrix multiplying each point with a matrix called T (shape = 3 X 3).

### Test with Numpy:

```py
def transform(pnt_cloud, T):
    
    i = 0
    for pnt in pnt_cloud:
        xyz_pnt = np.dot(T, pnt)
        
        if xyz_pnt[0] > 0:
            arr[i] = xyz_pnt[0]
            
        i += 1
           
    return arr
```

Calling the following code and calculating runtime (using %time) gives the output:

```
Out[190]: CPU times: user 670 ms, sys: 7.91 ms, total: 678 ms
Wall time: 674 ms
```

### Test with Pytorch Tensor:

```py
import torch

tensor_cld = torch.tensor(pnt_cloud)
tensor_T   = torch.tensor(T)

def transform(pnt_cloud, T):
    depth_array = torch.tensor(np.zeros(pnt_cloud.shape[0]))

    i = 0
    for pnt in pnt_cloud:
        xyz_pnt = torch.matmul(T, pnt)
        
        if xyz_pnt[0] > 0:
            depth_array[i] = xyz_pnt[0]
            
        i += 1
            
        
    return depth_array
```

Calling the following code and calculating runtime (using %time) gives the output:

```
Out[199]: CPU times: user 6.15 s, sys: 28.1 ms, total: 6.18 s
Wall time: 6.09 s
```

NOTE: Doing the same with torch.jit only reduces 2s

I would have thought that PyTorch tensor computations would be much faster due to the way PyTorch breaks its code down in the compiling stage. What am I missing here?

Would there be any faster way to do this other than using Numba?

Comment: Quibble: how are you multiplying a point of shape (3,) with matrix of shape (4,4)? Aren't the dimensions incompatible?

Comment: is it possible pytorch is accumulating gradients for this operation?

Comment: Ohh yes, there is a fourth term I removed that to make the question more understandable and general, and forgot to reduce the size of the other matrix. I've edited the question, thanks for pointing that out Natchiket

Answer (score 2):

For the speed, I got this reply from the PyTorch forums:

1. operations of 1-3 elements are generally rather expensive in PyTorch as the overhead of Tensor creation becomes significant (this includes setting single elements), I think this is the main thing here. This is also the reason why the JIT doesn’t help a whole lot (it only takes away the Python overhead) and Numby shines (where e.g. the assignment to depth_array[i] is just memory write).
2. the matmul itself might differ in speed if you have different BLAS backends for it in PyTorch vs. NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a for loop??
Why do you compute a 3x3 dot product and only uses the first element of the result??

You can do all the math in a single `matmul`:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
  depth_array = torch.matmul(pnt_cloud, T[:1, :].T)  # nx3 dot 3x1 -> nx1
  # since you only want non negative results
  depth_array = torch.maximum(depth_array, 0)
```

Since you want to compare runtime to numpy, you should disable [gradient accumulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63869655/1714410).

Comment: In the question above, I state that pnt_cld is a 100,000 x 3 matrix, i.e. each row is 1 x 3. I'm matrix multiplying each 1 x 3 vector with T (3x3). [nx3 dot 3x1 -> nx3 does not equal the above procedure]

Comment: Another thing I found was that tensor operations just by themselves don't accumulate gradients. The only accumulate gradients when the operation is in regards to a nn.model object.

Comment: @dankpenny  I updated the comment in the code regarding matrix sizes. Since you only use one element of the result - you can multiply by a  3x1 row of the matrix, rather than the entire matrix.

Comment: Ohh yess, my bad haha!