# Convert and save PytorchTensor to .mat image on GPU in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pytorch, gpu

I am a beginner in Pytorch and I am stuck on a question for days. I  want to save a image which is in Pytorch tensor form  as .mat file. I looked but there doesn't seem to be a direct method on converting Pytoch tensors to .mat file. One possible solution which I found was to convert it to numpy array, but since I am using Nvidia GPU, when I try converting Pytorch tensor to numpy array it gives me this error :

`fake_images[0] = fake_images[0].numpy()`

`TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first`

How do I save Pytorch tensor to .mat file while using GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Do as you are told:

```py
from scipy.io import savemat

with torch.no_grad():
  mdic = {'fake_images': [f_.cpu().numpy() for f_ in fake_images]}
  savemat('fake_images.mat', mdic)
```

You can see some more information on converting pytorch tensors to numpy arrays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63869655/1714410).