# Iterating over torch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, iteration, tensor

What is the best and fastest way to iterate over Tensor. It is confusing why do I get tensor instead of value..

got this :

```
  [ x for x in t]
  Out[122]: [tensor(-0.12), tensor(-0.11), tensor(0.68), tensor(0.68), tensor(0.17)]
```

but expected this behavior :

```
  [ x for x in t.numpy() ]
  Out[123]: [-0.11932722, -0.114598714, 0.67563725, 0.6756373, 0.16548502]
```

I would prefer not to convert to numpy if possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With numpy everything is simpler because `np.arrays` are just a collection of numbers always stored on CPU. Therefore, if you iterate over an `np.array` you get these `float` numbers.
However, in PyTorch, tensors store not only numbers but also their gradients. Additionally, PyTorch tensors may be stored on CPU or GPU. Thus, in order to preserve all this "side-information", PyTorch returns single-element tensors when iterating over a tensor.

If you insist on getting simple "numbers" from a tensor, you can use [`tensor.item()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html):

```py
 [x.item() for x in t]
```

Or, [`tensor.tolist()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.tolist.html):

```py
t.tolist()
```

For more information on the differences between numpy `np.array`s and `torch.tensor`s, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63869655/1714410).